# Modeling interest rates with correlation

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to model interest rates, and will use the following equation:

$dr = \mu r dt + \sigma r dW $

I'm also being told that interest rates are 40% correlated to S&P returns.  How can I include correlation to the S&P into this equation?  (It is pretty weird that interest rates are being correlated to S&P returns)

Comment: First, that is a diffusion equation usually used to model equities. Mainly because interest rates are assume to mean revert to some long range target. A better model would be the Vasicek model. Second, what is the function that is dependent on the diffusion?

Comment: What short rate model is this that multiplies $r$ with drift and $r$ with diffusion? What probability measure is this specified under?

Answer (score 5):

The model you assume for the interest rate process is a [Geometric Brownian Motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion).

As strimp099 highlights in his comments it is mainly used to model equities because you most of the time want your interest rate models to be *positive* and *mean reverting*.

A few models have been developed: [Vasicek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasicek_model), [CIR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox%E2%80%93Ingersoll%E2%80%93Ross_model), [HW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hull%E2%80%93White_model). You could have a pick in there.

As for the correlation, the idea is to make your process $r_t$ rely on a *multi-dimensional* Brownian motion, for example 2-dimension, where the first one is specific to the interest rate process and the other one is the brownian motion used in the equities model (representing your S&P 500).

Example:

$$dr_t=a(b-r_t)dt+\sigma(dW^1_t+dW^2_t)$$

with

$$dS_t = \mu S_t dt + \sigma S_t dW^2_t$$

This is how you "induce" correlation; by having the same Brownian motion in the dynamics of the two processes. You could also have $r_t$ occuring somewhere in $dS_t$.

In your question, you discuss about the S&P, but it's really important to understand that including the correlation requires you to define a model for S&P as well, which is the $S_t$ in my example.

Comment: For what it's worth, if he is trying to model interest rates with, say, a 1 week horizon then GBM is not a horrible approximation.  The mean reversion term would be negligible over such a period.